# How to make a list from multiple rows from inner join in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a view model called `Pictures` like

```
Public class PicturesViewModel
{
    public string Name;
    Public List<String> FileNames;
}
```

and I have 2 tables in a SQL Server database, `Names` and `FileNames`, where the `idname` in `FileNames` is a foreign key to `id` in `Names`.

[This screenshot shows the 2 tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdksR.png)

I use Entity Framework Core in an ASP.NET Core MVC project. I have to use the database first method and I want to fill `PicturesViewModel` class in my controller and send it to a view.

The problem is that I can't find a way to create a `PicturesViewModel` object from `DbContext` with linq and Entity Framework. The only way I can consider is to do it by C# (for or foreach) and do it with 2 steps:

- first filling `Name`
- then filling `FileNames` with a for/foreach loop

Is there another way in Linq or Entity Framework to create a list from an inner join in `dbContext` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model:

```
Public class Filenames
{
    public decimal idName { get; set; }
    public string fileNames { get; set; }
    public Names Names { get; set; }
}

Public class Names 
{
    public decimal id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Basically:

With Join basic (Bad) =>

```
Context.Names.Join(Context.Names.Filenames,
                   nam => nam.id,
                   fil => fil.idName,
                   (nam, fil) => new { filename = fil, names = nam });
```

With Navigation properties (Common in DB First) =>

```
Context.Names.Include("Filenames");
Context.Names.Include(ent => ent.Filenames);
```